# Is it possible to define a family of fundamental sequences for all countable (limit) ordinals? (Without AC)

Tags: logic, ordinals

A fundamental sequence for a limit ordinal $\lambda$ is a sequence of ordinals who converge to it.

A family of fundamental sequences for $\lambda$ is a function $F$ that assigns a fundamental sequence for all limit ordinals below $\lambda$.

At least, that is the definitions I'm working with. I don't mind if you have others. I think it is known that you may define a family of fundamental sequences for all ordinals below $\omega_1^{CK}$, and that without AC you can't do it for $\omega_1$.

I was wondering whether you can define famlies for all countable ordinals or if this also stops before $\omega_1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "define"?

Comment: Honestly? I'm not really sure. Prove that it exists in $ZF$, maybe. I know that isn't "define", but I would be happy with doing that.

Comment: Building off of Eric's answer: note that the fact that $\omega_1$ can have countable cofinality means that there can be no "nice" way to "uniformly" define a fundamental sequence for a given countable ordinal ("uniformly" meaning that we're using roughly the same strategy to define fundamental sequences, in all cases). It sounds like you're already aware of this from your question; if not, let me know and I'll undelete my answer (which discussed exactly this point).

Comment: I'm aware of what you say, @Noah, but please undelete it and I'll upvote it. I think it's useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming "define" just means "prove it exists", this is possible for any countable ordinal in ZF.  Indeed, if $\alpha$ is a countably infinite ordinal, there exists a bijection $f:\omega\to\alpha$.  For any limit ordinal $\beta<\alpha$, we now define $F_\beta:\omega\to\beta$ recursively as follows.  Having defined $F_\beta(m)$ for all $m<n$, we define $F_\beta(n)$ as $f(N)$ for the least $N\in \omega$ such that $f(N)<\beta$ and $f(N)>F_\beta(m)$ for each $m<n$.

It is then easy to see by induction on $n$ that $F_\beta$ is increasing and $F_\beta(n)\geq f(n)$ for all $n$ such that $f(n)<\beta$.  It follows that $F_\beta(n)$ converges to $\beta$, since it is eventually greater than every ordinal less than $\beta$.  So, letting $F$ be the function $\beta\mapsto F_\beta$, we have a family of fundamental sequences for $\alpha$.

Comment: Can I ask you a follow-up question here? This isn't "constructive" in the sense that you don't actually exhibit the function, because you are using the bijection with $\omega$. I know of some families of fundamental sequences - built explicitly from systems of ordinal notations. If I want to do something like _that_, how up can I go?

Comment: I think my real question is if you can have ordinal notations for any countable ordinal - as having a family of fundamental sequences for $\alpha$ seems to be equivalent to having an ordinal notation for it. I used to think that $\omega_1^{CK}$ was some kind of limit for this, and that there was an essential, unavoidable link between fundamental sequences and recursiveness, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @GuillermoMosse It depends what you mean by "ordinal notation." As usually used, the phrase refers to some *computable* notation system, so $\omega_1^{CK}$ is trivially an upper bound (and sometimes a sharp upper bound as e.g. in the case of Kleene notations). However, there is also a broader sense in which a notation is any sort of "concrete definition" for an ordinal, and this is sufficiently vague that such systems can arguably exist which go beyond $\omega_1^{CK}$. So you have to distinguish between effective notations, "concrete" fundamental sequences, and arbitrary fundamental sequences.

Comment: I have been reading and having discussions about the fundamental problem of defining the notion of ordinal notation. I understand now that there is a kind of trade-off between the length of your notation system and the "effectivity" (not just computability wise) of it.

Comment: Knowing the relationship between ordinal notations and fundamental sequences, maybe what I want to know can be rephrased like this: is it known whether a family of fundamental sequences can be defined for all ordinals below $\alpha$, for certain $\omega_1^{CK} < \alpha < \omega_1$? That was my suspicion: that without AC, we **had** to define this recursively, so we won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

In a strong sense, the answer is **no**:

> $(1)\quad$ It is consistent with ZF that there is no function $f$ which assigns to each countable limit ordinal a fundamental sequence for that ordinal.

This is a consequence of the simpler result that countable unions of countable sets need not be countable without choice:

> $(2)\quad$ It is consistent with ZF that $\omega_1$ has countable cofinality - that is, that there is an increasing sequence of infinite countable ordinals $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ whose supremum is $\omega_1$.

$(1)$ follows from $(2)$ as follows. Working in ZF, from a putative function $f$ assigning fundamental sequences to each limit ordinal we could by transfinite recursion build a function $g$ which assigns to each infinite countable ordinal a bijection between that ordinal and $\omega$. But in any model where $\omega_1$ has countable cofinality such a $g$ can't exist: if $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of infinite countable ordinals cofinal in $\omega_1$, then **from a sequence $h_n$ of bijections from $\alpha_n$ to $\omega$** we would get a bijection between $\omega_1$ and $\omega$, and obviously this can't happen.

Comment: I interpreted the question as asking for a family of fundamental sequences for each countable ordinal separately, rather than for all at once.  After all, they mentioned knowning that it is not possible for $\omega_1$, which is the same as doing all countable ordinals at once.

Comment: @Noah, can I ask you a followup question? The fact that $\omega_1$ has countable cofinality doesn't imply (in ZF) that the ordinal is countable. Right?

Comment: @GuillermoMosse The definition of $\omega_1$ is "the least uncountable ordinal," so even if $\omega_1$ has countable cofinality *(which would contradict the axiom of choice)* it is still uncountable. The issue is that "the countable union of countable sets is countable" is not provable in ZF alone.

Answer (score 0):

If by "define" it is meant "prove to exist", then the answer is yes, but if by "define" you mean to give an explicit notion of describing a fundamental sequence system for **all** ordinals $<\omega_1$, then no. For any (limit) ordinal $<\omega^{CK}_1$ you can always assign a family of computable fundamental sequences for all ordinals up to it, and you can do the same for up to any ordinal $\omega^{CK}_1\leq\alpha<\omega_1$ but it will necassarily be uncomputable.

You can prove a family of fundamental sequences up to $\omega_1$ exists, and it is consistent with ZFC and follows from the axiom of choice, but you can never give one explicitly, nor can you prove that the one you give actually works as a fundamental sequence system. In short, you can't give a formula which *provably*
defines such a fundamental sequence system.

Comment: "defining a fundamental sequence for all ordinals up to $\omega_1$ can only be possible if you can define a fundamental sequence for $\omega_1$ itself" Why would that be true?

Comment: It is actually consistent with ZFC that there is a definable system of fundamental sequences for all countable limit ordinals (indeed, it follows from V=L), even though $\omega_1$ has no fundamental sequence itself. Your statement is simply false.

Comment: but is there an ordinal $\eta < \omega_1$ that has the property of it being impossible to constructively define a family of fundamental sequences for all ordinals up to $\eta$?

Comment: No. For any countable ordinal there can be given a family of fundamental sequences for all ordinals below it.